# How do I check for null/empty value in cshtml

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
<b>Start Date: </b>@employee["StartDate"].<br />
```

Using MVC Razor 3/C#, how can I check if `employee["StartDate"]` value is null/empty in the cshtml? So that if it is, I instead display:

```
<b>Start Date: </b>Unknown.<br />
```

I tried:

```
@if(employee["StartDate"] == null){<b>Start Date: </b>Unknown.<br />}
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: What does your employee model look like?

Answer (score 15):

Try

```
<b>Start Date: </b>@(employee["StartDate"] ?? "Unknown").<br />
```

`??` return the left-side value, or the right-side value if the left-side value is `null`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only worried about null or empty

```
@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee["StartDate"])?"Unknow":employee["StartDate"])
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using this:

```
@if(employee["StartDate"].ToString() == ""){<b>Start Date: </b>Unknown.<br />}
else{<Start Date: </b>@employee["StartDate"].<br />}
```

But is there a "cleaner" way to write this?

Comment: Is `employee["StartDate"]` a DateTime?  I don't see how calling `ToString` on a `DateTime` can give you an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

If startDate is a `DateTime` try to compare it with `DateTime.MinValue`.

If you have more problems you can put breakpoint in razor code to see what exactly is that field

Comment: Or they could use DateTime? and just check for null.  Why make more work for yourself to set the StartDate to MinValue if there is no value?

Comment: @IyaTaisho you misunderstood me. Because in question he wrote that he tried null check, I am sure that value is not null

Comment: But it's not necessarily the MinValue either...  It could be anywhere in between the min and max values for that matter if it wasn't null.  Hence why I say, it would be much easier if they had just used DateTime? to begin with and then you can compare to a null value.

Comment: But DateTime type by default does not have a null value, if you do not assign anything it will be MinValue

Comment: ...  If you have the type DateTime? (this means nullable) and set it to nothing, you get a null value...

Answer (score -1):

Have tried like below, I have tired similar null check, it should work

```
@if(employee["StartDate"] != DateTime.MinValue){
  <Start Date: </b>@employee["StartDate"].<br />
}
else{
  <b>Start Date: </b>Unknown.<br />
}
```